# Android: AsyncTask crashes when processing image

Tags: android, image, upload, android-asynctask

I want to upload an image to my webserver.
I have response from the server and all, so that's not the problem.
When I paste the following lines into the code, it mostly crashes.

I see a RuntimeException for AsyncTask in the debugger, that's all.

Another question: can I get the bitmap uncompressed into a byte array, so I can upload the original file with original file-ending?

Here are the problem lines:

```
        // create the image for the server
    Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Values.imageFilePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byte_array=stream.toByteArray();
        String byteString=Base64.encodeToString(byte_array, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And here is the whole asynctask-class, the code above is commented out and it runs.
What's the problem? (ProgressDialog will be created in the main activity)
u
Thanks.

```
    class UploadThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        private Context _context;
        private ProgressDialog pd;

        public UploadThread(Context context)
        {
            super();
            _context=context;
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
            String response="Android says \"Nothing happened.\"";       
            InputStream is = null;
            StringBuilder sb=null;

            //http post
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Values.hostname);

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // This is the Post data.
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("plog_android_upload","plogupload"));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thecomment",Values.comment));

                // get the image and process it.
//            Values.progressDialog.setMessage("Processing image..");
        // create the image for the server
    //  Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Values.imageFilePath);
    //    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    //    byte[] byte_array=stream.toByteArray();
    //    String byteString=Base64.encodeToString(byte_array, Base64.DEFAULT);

        //Values.progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading..");
        //nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("upload_file",byteString));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));

        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpresponse.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        response="Connection established.";
    }catch(UnknownHostException eu){    // gets thrown on unknown host.
        return "No connection!\n(or wrong hostname)";
    }catch(HttpHostConnectException ex){ // gets thrown on unknown connection.
         return "No connection!\n(or wrong hostname)";
    }catch(Exception e){
        return "Error in http connection:"+e.toString();
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        response="Server says: "+sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        response= "Error converting HTTP result: "+e.toString();
        return response;
    }

    return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // dismiss the progress dialog.
    Values.progressDialog.dismiss();
    // Show the user some feedback.
    Toast.makeText(_context,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
}
```

}

Comment: post the stack trace along with exact line number.

Comment: your problem is here
Values.progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading..");
because this is UI, and UI can't be touched from doInBackground.
and YES post some stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you used

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Values.hostname);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // This is the Post data.
            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("plog_android_upload","plogupload"));
            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thecomment",Values.comment));
```

should not to be executed in doInBackground, I have faced the same problem when i had to use arrayList in doInBackground, so I changed that part of code to onPreExecute() which is working in UIThread

Comment: It can't be a problem buddy.

Comment: are you sure? because my problem solved when I did this, though I dont know the inner play...